# How to compile glimmer2 template for Ember 2.8+

Tags: json, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli, htmlbars

Recently we have started a wide scale upgrade of our EmberJS system. And currently we are at 2.11 version of ember.
With EmberJS 2.11

> Ember.HTMLBars.template

and

> Ember.Handlebars.template

all come via a single template function and expect JSON (ie. compiled glimmer2 template)

Currently trying to get a simple "Hello world" message appeared.
I have routes working, but Ember.HTMLBars.template expect glimmer2 JSON.

How do I make "Hello world" glimmer template and compile it to JSON?

Ember expects JSON something like

```
Ember.TEMPLATES["test/fixtures/simple"] = Ember.HTMLBars.template({"id":null,"block":"{\"statements\":[[\"open-element\",\"p\",[]],[\"flush-element\"],[\"text\",\"Hello, my name is \"],[\"append\",[\"unknown\",[\"name\"]],false],[\"text\",\".\"],[\"close-element\"]],\"locals\":[],\"named\":[],\"yields\":[],\"blocks\":[],\"hasPartials\":false}","meta":{}});
```

I have got https://github.com/tildeio/glimmer built, but not sure what to do next.
At the end, I need to get basic hello_world.hbs to compile into JSON.
I am a very new person in this area.

Any help appreciated

Thank you

Dimi

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the purpose of this is.

You can use [ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile) to precompile a template like

```
const layout = hbs`{{if foo "bar" "baz"}}`;
```

Yeah, that's valid JS. See [tagged template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals).

Then you can use the compiled template in a component like this:

```
import Component from 'ember-component';

export default Component.extend({
  layout;
});
```

There might be better options. Please read http://xyproblem.info , then provide details about your original problem.